# tkinter.tclError unknown option "-bd"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am started following an instructable link and there I'm doing an exercise in which I have to code a calculator in Tkinter. But I am facing an error.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import Entry
def process():
   try:
    number1=Entry.get(E1)
    number2=Entry.get(E2)
    operator=Entry.get(E3)
    number1=int(number1)
    number2=int(number2)
    if operator =="+":
       answer=number1+number2
    if operator =="-":
       answer=number1-number2
    if operator=="*":
       answer=number1*number2
    if operator=="/":
       answer=number1/number2
    Entry.insert(E4,0,answer)
    print(answer)
   except ValueError:
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Warning","Please enter the value in integer")

top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text = "Physics")
L1.place(x = 10,y = 10)
E1 = Entry(top,bd=5)
E1.grid(row=1,column=1)
L2 = Label(top, text="Number 1",).grid(row=1,column=0)
L3 = Label(top, text="Number 2",).grid(row=2,column=0)
L4 = Label(top, text="Operator",).grid(row=3,column=0)
L4 = Label(top, text="Answer",).grid(row=4,column=0)
E2 = Entry(top,bd =5)
E2.grid(row=2,column=1)
E3 = Entry(top,bd =5)
E3.grid(row=3,column=1)
E4 = Entry(top,bd =5)
E4.grid(row=4,column=1)
B=Button(top, text ="Submit",command = process).grid(row=5,column=1,)

top.mainloop()
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
File "f:/za/python/first.py", line 28, in <module>
E1 = Entry(top,bd=5)
File "D:\K.Hasan\Photos\New folder\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 669, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, widget or "ttk::entry", kw)
 File "D:\K.Hasan\Photos\New folder\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 557, in __init__
tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
File "D:\K.Hasan\Photos\New folder\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bd"
```

any ideas?

Can anyone pls solve the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting this error. ttk.Entry does have a `bd` option..https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Entry.html... you can try `from tkinter import Entry` instead of `from tkinter.ttk import Entry`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `ttk.Entry` does not have a `bd` option.

> See the documentation [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Entry.html)

You should change

```
from tkinter.ttk import Entry
```

to

```
from tkinter import Entry
```

⠀

⠀
Or in your case just remove this one line:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Entry
```

Since you already have:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Then it will work. Hope it helps :)

Comment: oh i missed the line `Tkinter Entry options not in ttk.Entry`